# Apart from Visual Studio, is there any tool we can use to debug JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am wondering if any tool other than Visual Studio exists to debug JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firebug, Chrome Debugger, Safari Developer Tools, Internet Explorer dev tools, Opera Dragonfly…

Comment: I would not know how debugging JavaScript in my IDE would be of any practical use... In-browser tools are the only useful option. +1!

Answer (score 1):

Firebug for Firefox is an excellent tool for debugging javascript.

This can be found here: http://getfirebug.com

Be warned if you use Firefox for browsing, that firebug can cause Firefox to become unstable with certain websites like Google Mail, but you can turn it off for any sites that you regularly use and have issues with, it also has it's own plugin system with lots of very useful development tools.

A very good alternative studio is netbeans http://netbeans.org/
You can also use this to debug your javascript files too amongst other things, we find that this studio is excellent for programming in php.

Both products are free to use.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox with Firebug Addon installed